# Are there games with player programmable vehicle control behaviour?

Tags: physics, software-engineering, modding

### My question

Are there any (space/flying/driving) games where the player can customize the mapping between player controls and the input to the vehicle actuators/engines programmatically? (Yes or no.)

```
                 ----------------                      ---------------
Player input -> | Control system | --Vehicle input--> | Vehicle model | -+-> Vehicle motion
                 ----------------                      ---------------   |
                        ^                                                |
                        |                                                |
                        +------------Feedback (optionally)---------------+
```

Basically games where the control system in the diagram above is replaceable by custom code.

**Edit:**

Just found out that Star Citizen [plans to implement this](https://robertsspaceindustries.com/comm-link/transmission/15031-Star-Citizen-Alpha-20-Flight-Model-Changes) to some extent. But my question is if there are any such games today?  (Yes or no.)

### Why I'm asking

I'm curious to see what would happen if a game only imposed physical models of vehicles and let players choose how to adjust controls. I've been thinking about this on and off for some time, but never found it implemented.

For example, in spaceflight games the default could be a mode where say the roll is automatically stabilized, players could then modify this code to instead take full control over the thrusters, or just tune the aggressiveness of the stabilization down a notch. Since all ships have the same capabilities, this would allow a kind of individual modding posing no fairness problems in multiplayer.

I imagine some hardcore players would really like this, and it could be cool if players started sharing/trading settings to tune their ships. Maybe even making it possible to trade control systems as in-game items.

If sufficient signals where exposed through an external interface, it would even be possible to write complete autopilots in your language of choice. I would love to teach automatic control using a game. :)

Comment: If the problem with my question is that it can turn into an enumeration scenario, I've clarified that I'm asking if anyone's implemented such a system to date. Is this ok, or is the subject unsuitable for GD.SE?

Comment: Whether or not somebody has done it is a yes/no question, which is generally not suitable (as is asking for a list of people who have; they are effectively the same question). You might try on a forum like [GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net).

Comment: Ok, thanks! I didn't get the "Yes/No" -> "Too broad" from the help center description of too broad, but trust you know these things. :) Btw, I take it the same rules apply at the gaming stack exchange?

Comment: I'd guess so, but I am not sure as I don't spend that much time there.

Comment: The reason yes/no == listing is that the justification for a "yes" is an example, and "no" is probably impossible to prove. You end up with the same answers as if you had asked for a list. I'd say the answer is "yes" in any case--I can think of a few games that use this idea.

Comment: Makes sense. I thought the issue was that it would be difficult to accept one answer, but in the yes/no case it would be the first proof and then finito. Can I ask you for these titles somewhere else? :) If you're on gamedev.net then here's my topic: https://www.gamedev.net/topic/672883-programmable-vehicle-control-behaviour/